# Agrupar en mongoDB (Agregate)

Tags: mongodb

tengo una duda y a la vez una consulta estoy trabajando con una colleción de datos, que es la siguiente

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d44bb2359f39d0ba947b6ea"),
        "actividad" : "V",
        "fechaInicial" : ISODate("2019-07-23T16:15:00.000Z"),
        "codVendedor" : "140",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d44bb2359f39d0ba947b6oa"),
        "actividad" : "LL",
        "fechaInicial" : ISODate("2019-07-23T16:15:00.000Z"),
        "codVendedor" : "150",
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d44bb2359f39d0ba947b6ia"),
        "actividad" : "LL",
        "fechaInicial" : ISODate("2019-07-23T16:15:00.000Z"),
        "codVendedor" : "140",
}
```

quisiera agrupar en base a la fecha y el codigo , por dia de la fecha
adjunto mi código que he estado probando y aun no me sale

```
db.getCollection('actividad').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match : {
            $and : [
                {fechaInicial: { $gte : ISODate("2019-07-23T00:00:01")}},
                {fechaInicial: { $lte : ISODate("2019-07-23T23:59:59")}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            codVendedor: 1,
            sum_visitas : {$cond: [ { $eq: ["$actividad", "V"] }, 1, 0]},
            sum_llamadas :{$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$actividad", "LL"] }, 1, 0]}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$codVendedor",
            total_visitas: {$sum : "$sum_visitas"},
            total_llamadas : {$sum : "$sum_llamadas"},
        }
    }

])
```

como ven aplico condiciones para lo que es V o LL pero solo por codigoVendedor , pero ahora necesito por fecha , los registro.
agradecería su ayuda. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según veo en tu código, creo que el problema esta en que no estas escribiendo bien el campo de `codVendedor`, ya que según creo entender en los documentos lo nombras `código`. Siendo esto cierto, si quieres agrupar por uno o mas campos deberías de añadirlo al `$group`, te muestro una posible solución:

- Query

---

```
db.getCollection('actividad').aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            fechaInicial: { //Esto es lo mismo que tu código pero de otra manera
                $gte : ISODate("2019-07-23T00:00:01"),
                $lte : ISODate("2019-07-24T23:59:59")}            
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {. // Campos para agrupar
                codigo: "$codigo", 
                fechaInicial:"$fechaInicial"
            },
            total_visitas: {
                $sum:{ // El sumatorio lo puedes hacer aquí, eliminando la Etapa $project
                    $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$actividad", "V"] }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            total_llamadas : {
                $sum:{
                    $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$actividad", "LL"] }, 1, 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

- Resultado

---

```
[{
    "_id" : {
        "codigo" : "150",
        "fechaInicial" : ISODate("2019-07-23T16:15:00.000Z")
    },
    "total_visitas" : 0.0,
    "total_llamadas" : 1.0
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "codigo" : "140",
        "fechaInicial" : ISODate("2019-07-23T16:15:00.000Z")
    },
    "total_visitas" : 1.0,
    "total_llamadas" : 1.0
}]
```

Espero haber ayudado en tu problema.

Un saludo

Comment: ya lo habia solucionado , pero ese era la respuesta , muchas gracias